# Why Exception is caught within Spring Boot Controller by @ExceptionHandler but not by @ExceptionHandler in @ControllerAdvice?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

In a Spring Boot MVC application I have a controller which calls a service method:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class RegistrationController {

    @GetMapping({"/email-confirmation"})
    public String emailConfirmation(@RequestParam String token) {

        internalRegistrationService.confirmEmail(token);

        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(TokenExpiredException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleTokenExpiredException(Exception e) {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        //...
        return mv;
    }
}
```

This service method can throw different subtypes of `TokenException`:

```java
@Service
public class InternalRegistrationService {

    public void confirmEmail(String token) throws TokenException {

        emailTokenValidator.validate(token);
    }
}
```

The thrown exception is either of type `TokenException` or `TokenExpiredException`, which extends TokenException.

Additionally to the `@ExceptionHandler` inside the controller itself which catches the `TokenExpiredException` as expected, I have a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated GlobalExceptionHandler:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(TokenException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "out of cookies")
    public void handleTokenException(Exception e) {
        logger.debug("{}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

This handler method is meant to catch all other kinds of `TokenException` but the `TokenExpiredException`.

**Unfortunately this doesn't work as intended.** The exception is thrown inside a service method, which is called by the controller. According to this [post from Antoniossss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60285060/13609359), all exceptions bubbling through the controller should get deligated to the
`@ControllerAdvice` annotated GlobalExceptionHandler. However, it doesn't. Instead, the error results in an uncaught 500. Does anybody know why?

**Many thanks for any help**

### Edit

Sometimes I'm asking myself whether to be only little stupid or complete plemplem. After an hour of trial and error, debugging and coffee with and without cookies I just stumbled across the fact, that I have forgotten to include the ControllerAdvice to classpath scanning. My deeply shame...

However, I will let this code here be, until someone of the crew thinks to better get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your exception to be catched in the @ControllerAdvice, remove the @ExceptionHandler in the controller, or make it more specialized. I mean does not catch the Exception class in your controller

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sometimes I'm asking myself whether to be only little stupid or complete plemplem. After an hour of trial and error, debugging and coffee with and without cookies I just stumbled across the fact, I have forgotten to include the ControllerAdvise to classpath scanning. My deeply shame...